# How do I prevent aliasing in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to copy a array to a new array, and then change values in the second array without the first array being effected.

An example of this ,

```
my_arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
copy_arr = my_arr
copy_arr[0]*=2

my_arr    //  [2,2,3,4,5]
copy_arr  //  [2,2,3,4,5]
```

I changed only copy_arr , but both the array `my_arr` and `copy_arr` are changed. In Ruby , Assignment aliases objects, multiple variables  are  referencing the same object. 
How can I assign variable so that it can not create aliases , that can resolve my issue ??

Comment: [This short article](https://www.thoughtco.com/making-deep-copies-in-ruby-2907749) provides a good explanation of what's going on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call [`dup`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-dup) to duplicate the array:

```
my_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
copy_arr = my_arr.dup     # <- here

copy_arr[0] *= 2

my_arr   #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
copy_arr #=> [2, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Note that this isn't aliasing (in Ruby terms). Your variables were merely referring to the same object. You asked the object to change its first element by calling `[]=` and as a consequence, the change was reflected by both variables. In other words: you changed the object, not the variables.

Objects may be changed by sending them messages (i.e. calling methods), variables are changed by assignment. And re-assiging another object to any of the variables doesn't affect the other:

```
foo = 123
bar = foo

foo #=> 123
bar #=> 123

bar = "hello"      # <- only changes bar, not foo

foo #=> 123
bar #=> "hello"
```

This is very different from an actual [`alias`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html#label-alias) in Ruby:

```
$foo = 123
alias $bar $foo

$foo #=> 123
$bar #=> 123

$bar = "hello"     # <- changes both, $foo and $bar

$foo #=> "hello"
$bar #=> "hello"
```

Comment: `alias $bar $foo` : did not know this was possible.